# Parse network configuration file (/etc/network/interfaces) with Python

Tags: networking, python

I need to write script in Python to read/write `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
It is not parse-able with builtin module **ConfigParser** because there are no sections.

Is there any parser for such files? Or maybe Python module to manage network configuration?

Or maybe there are other ways to read/change network interfaces settings?!

Comment: If I look at the file on my pc, it looks like a simple text file with all data on a seperate line. what keeps you from writing your own parser/writer?

Comment: Yes. I had to write my own parser. But it was not easy task, because it's structure may be complex...

Comment: You should open source it!

Answer (score 2):

[Here you can find a Awk script](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/awk-scripts-for-reading-and-editing-ubuntu-etcnetworkinterfaces-file-part-22/) that can parse and modify `/etc/network/interface`, good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The [Debinterface](https://github.com/dggreenbaum/debinterface) library might be what you're looking for.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Include instructions on how to use this Debinterface library.